# how do you define the decimals indicator: E-3?

Tags: calculator

Sorry for the terrible question, but how do you define E-3, which is used in the calculators to indicate that the first 3 decimals in the number are not displayed ?

```
0.000563 = 5.63E-3
```

I need to write in my thesis something like: "Please, pay attention that the values are shifted by 3 decimals".

thanks

Comment: `x.yzwE-3 = x.yzw`$\cdot 10^{-3}$.

Comment: @Theo Buehler I actually need to write it down in words. Something like: "Please, pay attention, the values are shifted".

Comment: Well, I'd say: "Please pay attention that the *decimal point* is shifted three digits to the left because of the decimal exponent $10^{-3}$", but I'm no native speaker. Out of curiosity: What kind of thesis are you writing that you can't assume familiarity with this on the part of your readers? I for one learned that in elementary school, maybe 3rd or 4th grade. By the way: your equality is wrong: `0.000563 = 5.63E-4`

Comment: @Theo Buehler Readers surely know what decimal point is, but they might not realize it by reading the values of the table without "10^-3", because I'm not appending it to all table values.

Comment: Instead of closing this answer, why doesn't one of the people voting to close actually, you know, answer it?

Comment: Dear @user1729 : The question is apparently "Is there some other way I can rewrite this sentence in my thesis?" It's simultaneously nonmathematical, will only help a single person ever, has no good answer, and is admitted by the OP to be a "terrible question."

Comment: @rschwieb It is about communicating maths. If I am interpreting it correctly, the OP wants to make it clear than when they are writing 5.3 they *mean* 0.0053. Which is not as uncommon as you might think.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're writing about.  It's probably easier to just write $5.63\times10^{-3}$ in the place of $0.00563$ in a math text.  If you *really* don't want to write the $\times10^{-3}$ (for example, in a table), just say "please note that the values in this table represent the error(or whatever they represent) divided by $1000$."

If you're writing about something physical that has units (for example, distance) write: "Measurement is in millimeters" or "Measured in $\text{mm}$."